# Is the following conditional expectation property true for four random variables?

Tags: conditional-expectation

Given random variables $W,X,Y,Z$ satisfying $E(XY)=E(E(X|Z)Y)$ and $E(XW)=E(E(X|Z)W)$, must it hold that $E(XY)=E(E(X|Z,W)Y)$?

I tried the case with $X,Z,W$ being jointly gaussian, and the case with $X,Z$ being jointly gaussian with mixing parameter $W$ etc, in both cases $E(XY)=E(E(X|Z,W)Y)$ holds.

However, when I tried showing it generally using orthogonal projection of conditional expectation, the given orthogonality statements doesn't seem to imply anything.

Comment: Where is this exercise/question from?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to come up with anything definitive, but I did come up with this toy example that might be helpful to you.

In the first example, all three hold:  $E(XY)=E(E(X|Z)Y)$, $E(XW)=E(E(X|Z)W)$, and  $E(XY)=E(E(X|Z,W)Y)$

In the second example, none of the three hold.

```r
require(dplyr)

calc <- function(A, p) {
  stopifnot(sum(p) == 1)
  
  Ex <- sum(p*A$X)
  Ey <- sum(p*A$Y)
  Ez <- sum(p*A$Z)
  Ew <- sum(p*A$W)
  # E(X|Z)
  Exgz <- with(A, c(sum(X[Z==0]*p[Z==0])/sum(p[Z==0]), sum(X[Z==1]*p[Z==1])/sum(p[Z==1])))
  # E(E(X|Z))
  EExgz <- sum(p*Exgz[A$Z+1])
  stopifnot(Ex == EExgz)
  
  # E(X)E(Y)
  ExEy <- Ex * Ey
  # E(XY)
  Exy <- sum(p*A$X*A$Y)
  # E(E(X|Z)Y)
  EExgz_y <- sum(p*Exgz[A$Z+1]*A$Y)
  
  # E(X)E(W)
  ExEw <- Ex * Ew
  # E(XW)
  Exw <- sum(p*A$X*A$W)
  # E(E(X|Z)W)
  EExgz_w <- sum(p*Exgz[A$Z+1]*A$W)
  
  # E(X|Z,W)
  Exgzw <- with(A, matrix(c(sum(X[Z==0 & W==0]*p[Z==0 & W==0])/sum(p[Z==0 & W==0]), 
                            sum(X[Z==1 & W==0]*p[Z==1 & W==0])/sum(p[Z==1 & W==0]),
                            sum(X[Z==0 & W==1]*p[Z==0 & W==1])/sum(p[Z==0 & W==1]),
                            sum(X[Z==1 & W==1]*p[Z==1 & W==1])/sum(p[Z==1 & W==1])
  ), nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
  # E(E(X|Z,W))
  EExgzw <- sum(p*mapply(function(z,w) Exgzw[z+1,w+1], z=A$Z, w=A$W))
  stopifnot(EExgzw == Ex)
  # E(E(X|Z,W) Y)
  EExgzw_y <- sum(p*mapply(function(z,w) Exgzw[z+1,w+1], z=A$Z, w=A$W)*A$Y)
  
  cov_xy <- with(A, sum(p*(X - mean(Ex))*(Y - mean(Ey))))
  cov_xz <- with(A, sum(p*(X - mean(Ex))*(Z - mean(Ez))))
  cov_xw <- with(A, sum(p*(X - mean(Ex))*(W - mean(Ew))))
  cov_yz <- with(A, sum(p*(Z - mean(Ez))*(Y - mean(Ey))))
  cov_yw <- with(A, sum(p*(W - mean(Ew))*(Y - mean(Ey))))
  cov_zw <- with(A, sum(p*(Z - mean(Ez))*(W - mean(Ew))))
  
  return(list(Exy=Exy, ExEy=ExEy, EExgz_y=EExgz_y,
              Exw=Exw, ExEw=ExEw, EExgz_w=EExgz_w,
              EExgzw_y=EExgzw_y,
              cov=matrix(c(cov_xy,0,0,cov_xz,cov_yz,0,cov_xw,cov_yw,cov_zw), ncol=3, dimnames = list(c("X","Y","Z"), c("Y","Z","W")))))
}

################################################################################

A <- expand.grid(X=c(0,1), Y=c(0,1), Z=c(0,1), W=c(0,1))

p_x <- data.frame(X = c(0, 0, 1, 1),
                  Z = c(0, 1, 0, 1),
                  p_x = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.6))

A <- A %>% dplyr::inner_join(p_x, by = c("X", "Z"))

A$p_y <- ifelse(A$Y == 0, 0.15, 0.85)
A$p_z <- ifelse(A$Z == 0, 0.8, 0.2)
A$p_w <- ifelse(A$W == 0, 0.1, 0.9)

# P(X,Y,Z,W) = P(W)*P(Z|W)*P(Y|W,Y)*P(X|Z,W,Y)
#  = P(W)*P(Z)*P(Y)*P(X|Z)
p <- with(A, p_x * p_y * p_z * p_w)

calc(A, p)
#> $Exy
#> [1] 0.578
#> 
#> $ExEy
#> [1] 0.578
#> 
#> $EExgz_y
#> [1] 0.578
#> 
#> $Exw
#> [1] 0.612
#> 
#> $ExEw
#> [1] 0.612
#> 
#> $EExgz_w
#> [1] 0.612
#> 
#> $EExgzw_y
#> [1] 0.578
#> 
#> $cov
#>              Y             Z             W
#> X 6.505213e-19 -1.600000e-02 -1.301043e-18
#> Y 0.000000e+00  1.734723e-18  1.084202e-19
#> Z 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00 -1.084202e-19



################################################################################

A <- expand.grid(X=c(0,1), Y=c(0,1), Z=c(0,1), W=c(0,1))

A$p_z <- ifelse(A$Z == 0, 0.8, 0.2)

p_x <- data.frame(X = c(0, 0, 1, 1),
                  Z = c(0, 1, 0, 1),
                  p_x = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.6))

A <- A %>% dplyr::inner_join(p_x, by = c("X", "Z"))

p_y <- data.frame(Y = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                  X = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1),
                  Z = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
                  p_y = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6))

A <- A %>% dplyr::inner_join(p_y, by = c("Y", "X", "Z"))

A$p_w <- c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.99, 0.98, 0.97, 0.96, 0.95, 0.94, 0.93, 0.92)

# P(X,Y,Z,W) = P(Z)*P(X|Z)*P(Y|Z,X)*P(W|X,Y,Z)
p <- with(A, p_x * p_y * p_z * p_w)

calc(A, p)
#> $Exy
#> [1] 0.464
#> 
#> $ExEy
#> [1] 0.50592
#> 
#> $EExgz_y
#> [1] 0.5072
#> 
#> $Exw
#> [1] 0.65232
#> 
#> $ExEw
#> [1] 0.6530176
#> 
#> $EExgz_w
#> [1] 0.653616
#> 
#> $EExgzw_y
#> [1] 0.5073216
#> 
#> $cov
#>          Y       Z           W
#> X -0.04192 -0.0160 -0.00069760
#> Y  0.00000 -0.0128 -0.00287808
#> Z  0.00000  0.0000 -0.00598400
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: How should I use your constructions to help solve the original problem?  I am still at lost.

Comment: I am also at a loss.  I was searching for a situation where the first two conditions were true, but the third is not so that I could understand the underlying reason.  I was exploring the covariance between the RVs to see if that could be the cause.  I agree this isn't a complete answer, but I shared in the hope it would help.  This is an interesting question.

Comment: Thanks for your interest and experiment.  I tried to solve it in the same way as you.  It is indeed a simple question (in appearance) but profound.  To my surprise, it didn't draw much attention even after a bounty :).  Probably it takes too long time to "search".